# How to create Check entry at quicbooks using PHP sdk

Tags: php, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I want to create Check entry using API at quick-books but API explorer does not have any info about it.

https://developer.intuit.com/v2/apiexplorer?apiname=V3QBO

How to create Check entry using PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For QuickBooks Online you would use the Purchase transaction type. Purchase transactions can be either Cash, Check, or Credit Card type.
[https://developer.intuit.com/docs/api/accounting/purchase](http://%20https://developer.intuit.com/docs/api/accounting/purchase)

Comment: got it ... Thanks :)